# How to clear the external heap memory in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory, memory-management

Memory leak issue is there in my project.I need to resolve it.
Initial memory is 15.7 MB and External memory is 79.2 KB
[image]

After performed some operation and clicked GC
Final memory is 31.5 MB and external memory is 16.6 MB
[image]

Instance 6 in External memory having 7.92 MB.Could not find where it is stored in project.
I clicked that instance 6 and it shows nothing.
[image]

I need to clear that memory.But I have no idea to clear the external memory.Kindly help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to find the root cause of your memory leak if we don't have the code but i suspect that you are not using dispose in your screen. It will clean object when code detect that the state object will never build again.

Documentation :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/dispose.html

Exemple:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  focusScopeNode.dispose(); 
  for (final _RouteEntry entry in _history)
    entry.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have used dispose method for all state class which I have created.But couldnt find the root cause

Comment: how are you using navigator to change route. Do you use navigator pushnamed, pushreplacementname. push .... ? Maybe your screen are stacking.